# How to implement two way binding for Angular and Polymer web components?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, polymer, angular-ui, dart-polymer

I have come across a [blog post](http://blog.sethladd.com/2014/02/angular-and-polymer-data-binding.html) by Seth Ladd with Dart code implementation but I am looking for a workaround. Is there any other angular-polymer project with bidirectional binding in JavaScript or any other language?

I am scouting at this point for right stack to implement. I find Laravel5-Bootstrap not the best combination. Whereas Laravel-Angular-material design has lot of unknown areas to begin with. I am quite sceptical for such implementation and hence the question if there is workaround for angular-polymer, I would be going with angular-polymer over angular-Material design. Now suggested solution to two way binding is in Dart, which is I am unable to comprehend whether it will go together with kind of stack I want to implement.

Specifics wouldn't be possible at this point. I will keep updating for specific issue.

Comment: Can you please quote the relevant parts of the post in your question? It will prevent this thread from becoming dead in a few months time and give us more specific points to work with.

Comment: I have edited the question. nothing specific but I need ideas.

Comment: I still don't get it what the actual question is or what problem you try to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go for [`AngularMaterial`](https://material.angularjs.org/)  is an implementation of Material Design in Angular.js. This project provides a set of reusable, well-tested, and accessible UI components based on the Material Design system which supports two way binding as well.

Comment: Would it be a good Idea if I try to integrate this with laravel 5 ? Bootstrap implementation for frontend is not convincing enough. There are too much Unknown areas for integration of L5-ngMD and cannot find any examples for such integration. I am scouting to create a better stack. would it be crazy to think of such stack implementation ?

Comment: Yes, i think so, you could go through this link for samples and templates http://materialdesignblog.com/

Comment: Thank you !! this has helped me, also I updated controller as <% %>  since L5 and ng has same bracket convention {{ }}



`$interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
$interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');`